# Show that ${{2k-2}\choose{k-1}}\le\frac{c\,4^k}{\sqrt{k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have to show this for an upper bound of diagonal Ramsey numbers $R(k,k)$. It is directly written on my teacher's notes that
$${{2k-2}\choose{k-1}}\le\frac{c\,4^k}{\sqrt{k}},$$ $c$ being a constant. I have tried expanding it but I failed to show that it's indeed true. Please help me out.

Comment: I simply expanded using the formula for n choose k. It led me nowhere. Can you please tell me how to proceed.

Comment: This will surely help. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

COMMENT.-This is extracted from the paper [https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204_2018/ramsey-numbers.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eapost/courses/18.204_2018/ramsey-numbers.pdf)

[image]

Comment: The figure is not accepted in the section of comments. I think your downvote express bad conscience. I put it just for helping, maybe, the OP.